# How to make a color in Listview

Tags: listview, vb6

How to make a color in subitem...

Listview

```
Listview1.Item(1).SubItems(2) 'I want ot make color on this column
```

How to do this.

Comment: Why does this question (and the others posted by this user) feel exactly like Gopal has returned under a new account?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you require (`intCol` is the zero based column you require the colour to be changed for):

```
Public Sub SetListviewItemColour(lvControl As ListView, intRow As Long, ByVal intCol As Integer, lngColour As Long)

    Dim liItem As ListItem
    Dim liSubItem As ListSubItem
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    On Error GoTo errHand

    Set liItem = lvControl.ListItems(intRow)
    If intCol = 0 Then
        liItem.ForeColor = lngColour
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    For intIndex = 1 To lvControl.ColumnHeaders.Count - 1
    If intIndex = intCol Then
        Set liSubItem = liItem.ListSubItems(intIndex)
        liSubItem.ForeColor = lngColour
        GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    Next

CleanUp:
    Set liItem = Nothing
    Set liSubItem = Nothing

    Exit Sub
errHand:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Call SetListviewItemColour(ListView1, 3, 1, vbRed)
```

Note I used the [code from VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=231157) as the basis for this snippet and extended it to use a column number